# Return list of words that appear directly before "word of interest"

Tags: mysql, regex

Essentially I have a column of long text values, ex:

```
ID | text 
0  | Hi my name is Brian.
1  | I think Brian sucks.
```

And I want to write a function that returns a list of words that come right before "word of interest". So if I searched "Brian", the function would return "is" and "think " because both words appear right before "Brian".
I have this code so far but it is not working:

```
select case when (select w.t regexp concat('[[:<:]]', w.v)) = 1 
    then substr(w.t, 1, locate(w.v, w.t)-1) else null end as 'left_word',
       w.v as word
    from (
        select text from table as t, "Brian" as v
    ) as w;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your query:

```
select text from table as t, "Brian" as v
```

should be:

```
select text as t, "Brian" as v from table
```

Once you fix that, your output is:

```
Hi my name is
I think
```

You can then use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to extract the last word out of those strings:

```
select case when w.t regexp concat('[[:<:]]', w.v, '[[:>:]]') 
            then substring_index(substr(w.t, 1, locate(w.v, w.t)-2), ' ', -1)
            else null
       end as 'left_word',
       w.v as word
from (
  select text as t, "Brian" as v
  from `table`
) as w;
```

Output:

```
left_word   word
is          Brian
think       Brian
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90483d/5)

Note for MySQL > 8.0.4, you need to use `\\b` as the word boundary instead of `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`, so your query becomes

```
select case when w.t regexp concat('\\b', w.v, '\\b') 
            then substring_index(substr(w.t, 1, locate(w.v, w.t)-2), ' ', -1)
            else null
       end as 'left_word',
       w.v as word
from (
  select text as t, "Brian" as v
  from `table`
) as w;
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fXD1TYdSghZtVLkhR29LvL/0)

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for your help and the SQLFiddle link, was not expecting this quick and clear of an answer. When I do run this code, it returns a "UNKNOWN_CODE_PLEASE_REPORT: Illegal argument to a regular expression." Any idea why?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: 8.0.18 is the version

Comment: Is it possible I just need to update to newer version of MySQL?

Comment: No, your version is too new for this code. You will need to use `concat('\\b', w.v, '\\b')` instead.

Comment: @bguan2020 I've updated my answer with code which will work on MySQL 8.0.18

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
select 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(text, 'Brian', 1),' ',-2) 
from `table` 
where text LIKE '%Brian%'
```